# If-Else for getIntent - Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have 2 activies. In first code, you see 2 rows and their click listeners. When first row clicked, I want to send "0" index to 2nd activity. As same, when I clicked second row, I want to send "1". So like that.
How can I do that?

Sender Side:

```
TableRow tricepsRow1;
    tricepsRow1=(TableRow) findViewById(R.id.arm_exercise_1);
    tricepsRow1.setClickable(true);
    tricepsRow1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             indexValueStandart=0;
            Intent tricepsRowIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),exercise_arm_triceps.class);
            tricepsRowIntent.putExtra("extra_arm_triceps",indexValueStandart);
            startActivity(tricepsRowIntent);
        }
    });

    TableRow tricepsRow2;
    tricepsRow2=(TableRow) findViewById(R.id.arm_exercise_2);
    tricepsRow2.setClickable(true);
    tricepsRow2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             indexValueStandart=1;
            Intent tricepsRowIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),exercise_arm_triceps.class);
            tricepsRowIntent.putExtra("extra_arm_triceps2",indexValueStandart);
            startActivity(tricepsRowIntent);
        }
    });
```

Receiver Side:

```
int getVIndexValue= getIntent().getIntExtra("extra_arm_triceps",0);
deneme.setText(String.valueOf(getVIndexValue));
```

Comment: So what is the error? Write some more information

Comment: There is no error. I just can't find a way to do that.

Comment: This code looks like it'll work , so what isn't working if there isn't an error?

Comment: This code is like task. I decided 2 rows which able to click and they have their IDs like 0,1...

Receiver side just gets one of the ID. I want to make like switch case in Receiver Side like;
if received id is ...
   do ...

I only get which one I want. I need to declare a variable and this variable must store the ID which come from sender side, but I can't make the system.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
int value = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("extra_arm_triceps");
```

Comment: Not sure how that's any different than the question. Those methods are the same

Comment: I want to check which one clicked and got id. I don't think this one can do.